# Does an integer $9<n<100$ exist such that the last 2 digits of $n^2$ is $n$?

Tags: number-theory

> Does an integer $9<n<100$ exist such that the last 2 digits of $n^2$ is $n$? If yes, how to find them? If no, prove it.

This problem puzzled me for a day, but I'm not making much progress. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you check some small cases and see if any pattern appears?

Comment: Write a short program if it stumps you.

Comment: @copper.hat So, you think this would help. How precisely?

Comment: @Did: I'm not sure what you're asking; a short program would determine all such integers quickly? It takes all of a minute. In Python (needs reformatting): for n in range(10,100):
    if (n*n %100) == n:
        print "found %s" % (n)

Comment: @copper.hat Sure, one would get the answer in one minute (plus the time to write down the program)... And then what? This would bring zero insight about the situation (and we are not *really* interested in *the solution itself*, are we?). Insight might come from staring at the results and thinking hard about them to understand where they are coming from. So, one may as well try *from the start* to understand what is going on rather than being distracted from that by using a program, don't you think?

Comment: This is becoming rather patronizing, and I do not understand why. One can determine the integers that satisfy the requirements and then use that to see if any structure becomes apparent. In this particular example, it is not clear what insight is obtained other than noticing that $n^2-n \mod 100$ is zero, and this 'insight' is already imbedded in the program's characterization of the solution. So, to answer your question, yes, I do think it helps. Otherwise I would not have suggested it as an approach.

Comment: Did not mean to be patronizing, sorry if my comment sounded so to you. The crucial point is the following: if one has no idea about a proof and one is being *told* the solutions, which insight does one gain? To deduce a proof from the solutions (25 and 76) requires a kind of reverse engineering that I find more difficult than the exercise itself. But maybe this is me?

Comment: I, for one, welcome our new computer overlords.  But, more seriously, it's a benefit to understand *both* mathematical and computational methods for solving problems where possible.

Comment: Computers mean a solution indeed. But it corresponds to trial and error. And it is said that the only insight one could gain is the congruence relation, but this condition is only the question! If one could gain nothing more than the question itself, it deserves not to be called an insight at all, right? In this particular case, since the number is small, one could just try to list all numbers and then pick up the two answers, right? We often call trial and error not insights, however. For example, the solution by Math Gems enables us to see the structure of commutative rings, the insights...

Comment: @Did: Sorry I was cranky. I think both approaches are useful. I guess I would my suggestion as along the lines of 'draw a picture', 'plot the graph'. Not an end in itself, but a piece of a puzzle.

Comment: @copper.hat I see what you mean and I disagree: analogues are not to draw a picture or to plot a graph, it is to be told "The solutions are 25 and 76, now gimme a proof". A fact which I would not be able to use at all (except *once I solved the exercise*, to check that I did not miscalculate). But hey, surely we are all different, and this is good that we are, aint'it? :-)

Comment: You cannot escape the Borg.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We are solving $n(n-1)=n^2-n\equiv0\pmod{100}$. Since $\gcd(n,n-1)=1$, one of $n$ or $n-1$ must be a multiple of $4$ while the other must be a multiple of $25$.This leads to the equations
$$
\begin{align}
4x-25y=+1\tag{1}\\
4x-25y=-1\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
For $(1)$, $n=4x$ and $n-1=25y$. For $(2)$, $n=25y$ and $n-1=4x$.

Using the Euclidean algorithm, $(1)$ has solutions $(x,y)=(-6+25k,-1+4k)$ and $(2)$ has solutions $(6+25k,1+4k)$. The two solutions that give $4x$ and $25y$ between $9$ and $99$ are $(19,3)$ and $(6,1)$.

$(19,3)$ solves $(1)$ so $n=4x=76$ and $76^2=5776\equiv76\pmod{100}$

$(6,1)$ solves $(2)$ so $n=25y=25$ and $25^2=625\equiv25\pmod{100}$

Thus, the two integers that satisfy the given condition are $25$ and $76$.

Comment: Would you please explain why "one of n or n−1 must be a multiple of 4 while the other must be a multiple of 25"?

Comment: Because neither $n$ nor $n-1$ could be divisible by $100$.

Comment: @jasoncube: if either were divisible by both 4 and 25, then $n\equiv0\pmod{100}$ or $n-1\equiv0\pmod{100}$; that is, $n\equiv0\text{ or }1\pmod{100}$. However, neither $0$ nor $1$ is between $9$ and $99$.

Answer (score 5):

So, we need $n^2\equiv n\equiv{100}\iff 100\mid n(n-1)$

Now, $(n.n-1)=1$ and $100=2^25^2$

So,

either (i) $100\mid n\implies n=100k$  where integer $k\ge0$

So we need  $0<100k<100\implies 0<k<1$  which is not possible .

or (ii) $100\mid (n-1)\implies n=100k+1$ where integer $k\ge0$

So we need  $0<100k+1<100\implies 0<k<1$  which is not possible .

or (iii)  $4\mid n$ and $25\mid (n-1)$

(a) $n\equiv0\pmod 4$ and $n\equiv1\pmod{25}$

Applying well-known [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChineseRemainderTheorem.html),

$$n\equiv0\cdot b_1\cdot\frac{25\cdot4}4+1\cdot b_2\cdot\frac{25\cdot4}{25}\pmod{100}\equiv4b_1\pmod{100}$$

where $b_1\cdot\frac{25\cdot4}4\equiv1\pmod4$ and $b_2\cdot\frac{25\cdot4}{25}\equiv1\pmod{25}$

But we don't need $b_1$ as its coefficient is already $0$

and $4b_2\equiv1\pmod{25}\implies b_2\equiv4^{-1}\pmod{25}$

Using the [Convergent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_recurrence_formulas#The_determinant_formula) property of continued fraction, $\frac{25}4=6+\frac14$

So, the last but one convergent is $\frac61\implies 25\cdot1-4\cdot6=1\implies 4^{-1}\equiv-6\pmod{25}$

$\implies b_2\equiv(-6)\pmod{25}\implies x\equiv4(-6)\pmod{100}\equiv-24$

(b)We have $n=4d,n-1=25e\implies 4d-25e=1$

$\implies 25e=4d-1 \implies 25(e+1)=4(d+6)\implies \frac{4(d+1)}{25}=e+1$ an integer

So, $25\mid(d+6)$  as $(25,4)=1$  $\implies d=25f-6$ for some integer $f$

$\implies n=4d=4(25f-6)=100f-24$

Using $(a)$ or $(b),$  we need  $9<100f-24<100\implies  1\le f<2\implies f=1\implies n=76$

or (iv) $4\mid (n-1)$ and $25\mid n\implies n-1=4a,n=25b\implies 25b-4a=1$

Applying one of the two approaches  $(a),(b)$ mentioned above, we get $n=100c+25 $

So we need  $9<100c+25<100\implies  0\le c<1\implies c=0\implies n=25$

Comment: Would the down-voter please point out the mistake?

Answer (score 3):

this problem is equivalent to $n^2\equiv n \pmod{100}$. and by [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2-x=0%20mod%20100), solution of this equation is $n=25,76$.

Comment: Don't need no Alpha. Since $x$ and $x-1$ are relatively prime, one of $x$ or $x-1$ has to be divisible by $25$.

Comment: Two upvotes for summoning WA when there is no need? Hmmm...

Comment: @AndréNicolas: I didn't notice your comment before I wrote up my answer +1, for what it's worth.

Comment: @Did: perhaps Stephen W has an account here :-D

Comment: Notice that it is 3 upvotes minus 1 downvote here.

Comment: When I wrote my first comment it was +2-0. (FWIW I did not vote.)

Answer (score 3):

Write $n=10a+b$. Then $n² \equiv 20ab+b² \pmod{100}$. So the problem is reduced to solving $20ab+b²\equiv 10a+b \pmod{100}$. Hence $100|b(20a+b-1)-10a$. So $10|b(b-1)$. But $0\leq b<10$, thus either b is even and $b-1$ is divisible by $5$ or $b-1$ is even and $b$ is a multiple of $5$.
In the former case, $b$ must be $6$ and $100|110a+30$, viz. $a=7$ and $n=76$.
In the latter, $b$ must be $5$, so that $100|90a+20$, namely, $a$=$2$ and $n=25$.

Answer (score 1):

More generally, instead of $4,25,$ let $\rm\,p, q\,$ be coprime prime powers. By $\rm\,n,n\!-\!1\,$ coprime

$$\rm pq\,|\,n(n\!-\!1)\ \Rightarrow\ p\,|\,n\ \ or\ \ p\,|\,n\!-\!1\ \ \ and\ \ \ q\,|\,n\ \ or\ \ q\,|\,n\!-\!1$$

This yields $4$ possibilities. Write $\rm\: n \equiv (a,b)\,\ (mod\ p,q)\:$  for $\rm\:n\equiv a\,\ (mod\ p),\ n\equiv b\,\ (mod\ q)$

$$\begin{eqnarray}\rm p,q\,|\,n &\iff&\,\rm n \equiv (0,0)\ \ (mod\ p,q)\\
\rm p,q\,|\,n\!-\!1 &\iff&\,\rm n \equiv (1,1)\ \ (mod\ p,q)\\
\rm p\,|\,n,q\,|\,n\!-\!1 &\iff&\,\rm n \equiv (0,1)\ \ (mod\ p,q)\\
\rm p\,|\,n\!-\!1,q\,|\,n &\iff&\,\rm n \equiv (1,0)\ \ (mod\ p,q)\\
\end{eqnarray}$$

By CRT, $\rm\ mod\ pq\!:\ (0,0) \equiv 0,\:$ and $\rm\:(1,1)\equiv 1,\:$ and for the sought nontrivial idempotents:

$$\rm\begin{eqnarray}(1,0) \!&\equiv&\rm\, q(q^{-1}\ mod\ p)\,\ (mod\ pq)\ [\equiv 25(25^{-1}\ mod\ 4)\equiv \color{#C00}{25}\,\ (mod\ 100)\ \ if\ \ p,q = 4,25]\\ \\
\Rightarrow\ \ \rm (0,1)\! &\equiv& (1,1)-(1,0)\:[\equiv 1-25\equiv -24 \equiv \color{#C00}{76}]\end{eqnarray}$$

**Remark** $\ $ Readers familiar with ring theory may note that the pair $\rm\:(a,b)\:$ is naturally viewed as an element of the product ring $\rm\:\Bbb Z/p \times \Bbb Z/q \,\cong\, \Bbb Z/pq\:$ via CRT (by $\rm\:p,q\:$ coprime). Generally such product decompositons are governed by idempotents (e.g. $(0,1),(1,0)),$ cf. [Peirce decomposition.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peirce_decomposition)

Comment: Marvellous application of ring-theory!

Comment: Thus, as an easy generalisation, one sees that, for $(p,q)=(8,125)$, the only two non-trivial answers are 625 and 376. In fact, it could be concluded easily that, for any $p, q$, there are always two answers. Thanks for the nice answer then.