# Number theory - congruence

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let $n$ be an even integer not divisible by $10$, what digit is in the $10$s place for $n^{20}$ and the hundreds place for $n^{200}$, can you generalise this?

I know that for $n^{20}$ they end in $76$ and for $n^{200}$ they all end in $376$
I even went on too see that $n^{2000}$ always ends in $9376$.

I was given a clue that $76$ is the only number that is divisible by $4$ that gives $1$ when working $\bmod{25}$, I'm not sure how to relate that and generalise

When working $\bmod{100}$ for $n^{20}$ I noticed, $100 = 4 \times 25 = 2^2 \times 5^2$ , so we looked at a number divisible by $4$ that gave $1$ when working in $\bmod{25}$.

Similarly for $n^{200}$, $1000 = 2^3 \times 5^3$, for which $376$ is divisible by $8$ and gives $1$ when working with $\bmod{125}$?

Am I looking along the right lines?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: See also [this related answer.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/292967/23500)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us first do the case $n^{20} \pmod{100}$.

You have been advised to split this into two problems

- $n^{20} \pmod{4}$. Since $n$ is even, this yields $n^{20} \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$ here.
- $n^{20} \pmod{25}$. Since $n$ is not divisible by $5$, we have $(n, 25) = 1$. Since $\varphi(25) = 20$, we obtain  $n^{20} \equiv 1 \pmod{25}$.

(Here $\varphi$ is [Euler's totient function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function).)

Now you solve the system of congruences
$$
\begin{cases}
x \equiv 0 \pmod{4}\\
x \equiv 1 \pmod{25}
\end{cases}
$$
which has the solution(s) $x \equiv 76 \pmod{100}$.

In the general case $k \ge 2$ you have $n^{2 \cdot 10^{k-1}} \pmod{10^{k}}$. Again, split it into two problems

- $n^{2 \cdot 10^{k-1}} \equiv 0 \pmod{2^k}$, as above.
- $n^{2 \cdot 10^{k-1}} \pmod{5^k}$. Since $n$ is not divisible by $5$, we have $(n, 5^k) = 1$. Since $\varphi(5^k) = 5^k - 5^{k-1} = 4 \cdot 5^{k-1}$, we obtain  $n^{2 \cdot 10^{k-1}} \equiv 1 \pmod{5^k}$.

Now you solve the system of congruences
$$
\begin{cases}
x \equiv 0 \pmod{2^k}\\
x \equiv 1 \pmod{5^k}.
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance but what exactly is φ(x) ?

Comment: @user61067, it's *Euler's totient function*, I have added a link in the answer.

Comment: Got it, thank you for all your help

Comment: @user61067, you're welcome!

Comment: Sorry, just to confirm, what do you mean when you say 'Since n is not divisible by 5, we have (n,25)=1'

Comment: @user61067, first of all, you assume $n$ is divisible by 2 but not by 10, thus it is not divisible by 5. Thus $n$ is coprime to $25$, that is, the greatest common divisor $(n, 25)$ between $n$ and $25$ is $1$.

Comment: It basically says if some number $q$ is not divisible by some **prime** $p$, then they must be coprime. 5 is a prime, and $n$ is not divisible by 5, since it's even, and not divisible by 10, hence $(n; 5) = 1$, hence $(n; 25) = 1$.

Comment: Ok I get it now, thank you both, sorry for the bother